# What wrong with my Arduino code?

Tags: arduino-uno, arduino-ide, rotary-encoder

I have a rotary encoder (ppr = 600) and I want to write code to achieve the implementation to read current angle and direction.

Here is my code. I think it is correct but it donot have any output on the serial monitor.

```
#include <Servo.h>

// Rotary Encoder Connections
int encoderPinA = 2;  // Connect the CLK pin of the encoder to digital pin 2
int encoderPinB = 3;  // Connect the DT pin of the encoder to digital pin 3

// Variables
volatile int encoderPos = 0;   // Current position of the encoder
volatile int lastEncoderPos = 0;  // Previous position of the encoder
int clockwiseSteps = 0;  // Total clockwise steps turned
int counterclockwiseSteps = 0;  // Total counterclockwise steps turned
int latestOperation = 0;  // Latest rotation operation (1 for clockwise, -1 for counterclockwise)
int degreesPerStep = 360 / 600;  // Degrees per step for a 600-pulse rotary encoder
int aLastState = digitalRead(encoderPinA); // Default state of Pin A

void setup() {
    // Set encoder pins as inputs
    pinMode(encoderPinA, INPUT_PULLUP);
    pinMode(encoderPinB, INPUT_PULLUP);

    // Attach interrupts to the encoder pins
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(encoderPinA), updateEncoder, CHANGE);
    attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(encoderPinB), updateEncoder, CHANGE);

    // Initialize Serial communication
    Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {
    // Print the total degrees turned in both directions
    if (encoderPos != lastEncoderPos) {
        int rotation = encoderPos - lastEncoderPos;
        if (rotation > 0) {
            clockwiseSteps += rotation;
            latestOperation = 1;
        } else {
            counterclockwiseSteps += rotation;
            latestOperation = -1;
        }
        lastEncoderPos = encoderPos;

        int currentAngle;
        if (latestOperation == 1) {
            currentAngle = (clockwiseSteps - counterclockwiseSteps) * degreesPerStep;
            Serial.print("CW | ");
        } else {
            currentAngle = (clockwiseSteps - counterclockwiseSteps) * degreesPerStep;
            Serial.print("CCW | ");
        }
        Serial.println(currentAngle);
    }
}

void updateEncoder() {
    int aState = digitalRead(encoderPinA); // Reads the "current" state of the outputA
   // If the previous and the current state of the outputA are different, that means a Pulse has occured
    if (aState != aLastState){     
   // If the outputB state is different to the outputA state, that means the encoder is rotating clockwise
     if (digitalRead(encoderPinB) != aState) { 
       encoderPos++;
     } else {
      encoderPos--;
     }
   } 
   aLastState = aState; // Updates the previous state of the outputA with the current state
 }
```

Why there is no output? Seem like the interrupt function not working. How to fix it?
[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you add the exact type of your rotary encoder (and the link to a datasheet, if you can find it)? Because your code reads a "raw" rotary encoder, but the pin names `CLK` and `DT` in your code comment suggest that the encoder rather speaks something like SPI. Also, all variables declared outside and used inside an interrupt handler should be declared `volatile`. `aLastState` does not have this flag.

Comment: We definitely need to know the part number of the rotary encoder and a link to the datasheet, or at least more information about it.

Comment: @NickGammon I update the information in the text

Comment: @orithena I modify int to volatile int, but still not work

Comment: I just got this information from my teacher.

Comment: This is a "raw" rotary encoder with open collector output, so `INPUT_PULLUP` should be right. Let's debug "no output at all". Add in your `setup()` after `Serial.begin(9600)`: `delay(100); Serial.println("----- Hello -----");`. If this is not printed on the Serial Monitor when you press the reset button, you probably have the wrong baud rate (i.e. not 9600) set in your Serial Monitor. If that works, add a simple volatile counter variable, increased unconditionally on each interrupt and printed unconditionally in each `loop()`. If this does not increase, there's something wrong with the wiring.

Comment: You can also remove the encoder and manually connect and disconnect the interrupt pins to/from ground. This will take the characteristics of the encore out of the equation.

Comment: `Add in your setup() after Serial.begin(9600): delay(100); Serial.println("----- Hello -----");` - so what happened when you did that? Please edit the question to describe.

Comment: Your tag Arduino-Uno is completely contradicted by your photograph showing a Arduino Mega 2560. Please edit the tags and get that part right. Also, you did not mention the part number of the encoder.

Comment: Since the interrupt routine only does anything if the A pin has changed, the second attachInterrupt line is not needed.  You don't need an interrupt for the B pin if you aren't going to react to changes on the B pin.

Comment: `int degreesPerStep = 360 / 600;` This integer division resolves to 0. Use a float datatype instead of int. If this solves the problem then create an answer showing the code changes you made.

Comment: `if (encoderPos != lastEncoderPos)`. This may cause sporadic problems. `encoderPos` is a 16 bit int. Your Mega is an 8 bit processor. If the interrupt comes during the time that this variable is read in the loop, the variable may be corrupted by the write operation in the interrupt handler. To eliminate that risk, use an noInterrupts()/interrupts() block to make a copy of `encoderPos`. (topic: non-atomic read operation. Note that this  is not the same as declaring the variable as volatile which signals the compiler not to retain possibly stale versions of the variable )